# error D8016: Incompatible '/clr' and '/await' command line options

Tags: c++, winapi

Supporting clr in winrt environment will throw an error.
(error D8016: Incompatible '/clr' and '/await' command line options.)

I want to use HwndSource in win32.
HwndSource must use clr.
But I need to use winrt, but I can't use it because of the above error.

Is there any way to replace HwndSource without using clr?

Comment: Whatever problem you have, HwndSource is most definitely not going to solve it.  WPF and WinRT are vastly different gui frameworks.